# Python 3.6 - Sanic Motorengine

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, sanic, motorengine

I am trying to setup the new `Sanic` web framework (which is promised to be extremely fast) with `motorengine` in order to achieve 100% async.

My setup so far:

```
app = Sanic(__name__)

@app.listener('after_server_start')
async def setup_dbconn(app, loop):
    connect("database_name", username="user", password="pass", host="192.168.1.200", port=27017, io_loop=asyncio.get_event_loop())
```

Unfortunately I get:

```
motorengine.connection.ConnectionError: Cannot connect to database default :
Unknown option username
```

Why does this crash?

Comment: i replaced motorengine with its synchronous equivalent mongoengine.. and it works as expected.. can anybody refer to this?

Answer (score 1):

The specific problem you encounter is not about `Sanic` but has to do with `motorengine`.

Use the database URI to connect:

```
motorengine.connect(
    db=name, 
    alias=alias, 
    host="mongodb://username:password@localhost:port", 
    io_loop=tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
)
```

The solution came from this ticket: https://github.com/heynemann/motorengine/issues/82.

---

**PS:** For Sanic >= 0.4.0 you should consider using [sanic-motor](https://github.com/lixxu/sanic-motor) extension!